# TSQL Replace Using Substring Replaces Other Parts of String As Well

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, replace, substring

I have a table made up of one column that has a 100 character string in each row. A second column was added to house the result. I needed to amend certain fix position elements and planned to do the following:

```
UPDATE myData
SET newData =  REPLACE(oldData,SUBSTRING(eftnwsfull, 16,2),'OC')
```

The element at position 16,2 is '17'. But, if there are other parts of the string (not at position 16,2) that happen to be '17' are getting changed to 'OC' as well.

I'm baffled to understand how this can happen as I'm specifying the exact position of where to make the replacement. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Thats expected; REPLACE replaces anything in its first argument than matches the second, with the third

Comment: I was under the impression that SUBSTRING would 'filter' it. OK, is there another way to do it?

Comment: Can you clarify what you want to replace, in what?

Comment: One of the best way of clarifying things is using an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [STUFF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx)

```
UPDATE myData
SET newData = STUFF(oldData, 16, 2, 'OC')
```

Comment: Cheers STUFF did the job perfectly. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of ways (please test as the offsets may be one off) ..

`SET newdata = SUBSTRING(oldData, 1, 15) + 'OC' + SUBSTRING(oldData, 18, LEN(oldData) - 17)`

or

`SET newdata = LEFT(oldData, 15) + 'OC' + RIGHT(oldData, LEN(oldData) - 17)`